# how to add remove button in combobox

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to create a ComboBox with the remove button like the picture below:

[image]

The picture uses Java Swing, and I don't know how to do this with JavaFX. I would like to create two ComboBoxes (a,b). When I click the "cross" in ComboBox a, I would like to remove a's item and add this item to ComboBox b, and ComboBox b so on.

**ComboBox a：**
**(1)click item then remove it from a and add on b**

**ComboBox b：**
**(1)click item then do something(ex:print item)**

**(2)click cross then remove it from b and add on a**

```
package UnitTest;

import Peer.Peer_Manager;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class temp extends Application {
    final int height = 200;
    final int weight = 300;
    final int offset = 5;
    Peer_Manager p_management;
    XYChart.Series series_hop;
    XYChart.Series series_gd;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox(); 
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5)); 
        vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: CORNSILK;");

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, weight, height);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        HBox hbBtn = new HBox();
        Text t1=new Text("  A：");
        Text t2=new Text("  B：");

        String[] filename = {"A","B","C"};//conf.load_all();
        ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<String>();
        cb.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(filename));
        cb.setVisibleRowCount(10);

        ComboBox<String> cb2 = new ComboBox<String>();
        cb.setVisibleRowCount(10);

        vbox.getChildren().add(hbBtn);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(t1);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(cb);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(t2);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(cb2);

        cb.setOnAction(e -> { 
            try {
                Object object = cb.getValue();
                if (object != null) {
                   cb2.getItems().add(object);
                   cb.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                   cb.getItems().remove(object);
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        //would like to do something(ex:print item),but don't remove
        //add the "cross" beside items,click "cross" to remove item and add on cb
        cb2.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                Object object = cb2.getValue();
                System.out.println(object);
                if (object != null) {
                    cb1.getItems().add(object);
                    cb2.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                    cb2.getItems().remove(object);
                }

            } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("SimulatorFX");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code at all?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve] of what you are having a problem with.

Comment: You can check out [CheckComboBox](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#checked) from ControlsFX.

Comment: @Joris sorry, i add the example now.(code and picture)

Comment: @TimPenner sorry, i add the example now.(code and picture)

Comment: @sillyfly sorry, i add the example now.(code and picture)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to implement a `cellFactory`. See the last item in [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/combo-box.htm)

Comment: @sillyfly I've read it . it seems not i need.
I've edit my question again ,it's my need:

ComboBox a： 
(1)click item then remove it from a and add on b

ComboBox b： 
(1)click item then do something(ex:print item)
(2)click cross then remove it from b and add on a

Comment: With a `cellFactory` you can provide the node to be displayed in the list. You can have buttong in it, and have the buttons have whatever logic you wish. I'll try to work on a more complete example for you.

Comment: @sillyfly thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way is to use a `CellFactory` and create graphic nodes that contain the elements you wish to have. Here is an example:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ComboBox<String> cba = new ComboBox<>();
    ComboBox<String> cbb = new ComboBox<>();
    cba.getItems().addAll("A", "B", "C");
    cbb.getItems().addAll("123", "456", "789");

    // Set a cell factory for ComboBox A. A similar thing should be done for B. 
    cba.setCellFactory(lv ->
            new ListCell<String>() {
                // This is the node that will display the text and the cross. 
                // I chose a hyperlink, but you can change to button, image, etc. 
                private HBox graphic;

                // this is the constructor for the anonymous class.
                {
                    Label label = new Label();
                    // Bind the label text to the item property. If your ComboBox items are not Strings you should use a converter. 
                    label.textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
                    // Set max width to infinity so the cross is all the way to the right. 
                    label.setMaxWidth(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
                    // We have to modify the hiding behavior of the ComboBox to allow clicking on the hyperlink, 
                    // so we need to hide the ComboBox when the label is clicked (item selected). 
                    label.setOnMouseClicked(event -> cba.hide());

                    Hyperlink cross = new Hyperlink("X");
                    cross.setVisited(true); // So it is black, and not blue. 
                    cross.setOnAction(event ->
                            {
                                // Since the ListView reuses cells, we need to get the item first, before making changes.  
                                String item = getItem();
                                System.out.println("Clicked cross on " + item);
                                if (isSelected()) {
                                    // Not entirely sure if this is needed. 
                                    cba.getSelectionModel().select(null);
                                }
                                // Remove the item from A and add to B. You can add any additional logic in here. 
                                cba.getItems().remove(item);
                                cbb.getItems().add(item);
                            }
                    );
                    // Arrange controls in a HBox, and set display to graphic only (the text is included in the graphic in this implementation). 
                    graphic = new HBox(label, cross);
                    graphic.setHgrow(label, Priority.ALWAYS);
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                }

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(graphic);
                    }
                }
            });

    // We have to set a custom skin, otherwise the ComboBox disappears before the click on the Hyperlink is registered. 
    cba.setSkin(new ComboBoxListViewSkin<String>(cba) {
        @Override
        protected boolean isHideOnClickEnabled() {
            return false;
        }
    });

    VBox vb = new VBox(cba, cbb);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vb));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Just adding that the `setSkin()` call can't be put anywhere, it took me time to find that running that after the constructor of a Controller caused the skin to be immediately `dispose()`d and that this was the source of a `NullPointerException` I was encountering when showing the `ComboBox`. Setting the new skin in the constructor solved that.